# Why does Sentinel S2L2A API request comes back with single-colored ROI?

Tags: python, sentinel-2, request

So here's the thing. I am trying to receive an image from S2L2A. When I use `bbox` as an input method, I get back normal picture in full colors. But when I switch to `Polygon` method, area comes back with desired shape, although in single color? It's my first time dealing with Sentinel, so I am lost. Please help me and point out my mistakes.

`bbox` data

```
sample_data={
    "input": {
        "bounds": {
            "bbox": [
                13.822174072265625,
                45.85080395917834,
                14.55963134765625,
                46.29191774991382
            ]
        },
        "data": [{
            "type": "sentinel-2-l2a"
        }]
    },
    "evalscript": """
    //VERSION=3

    function setup() {
      return {
        input: ["B02", "B03", "B04"],
        output: {
          bands: 3
        }
      };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(
      sample,
      scenes,
      inputMetadata,
      customData,
      outputMetadata
    ) {
      return [2.5 * sample.B04, 2.5 * sample.B03, 2.5 * sample.B02];
    }
    """
}
```

`Polygon` data

```
data = {
    'input': {
        'bounds':{
            'properties':{
              'crs': 'http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84'
            },
            'geometry':{
                'type': 'Polygon',
                'coordinates': [
                    coords
                ]
            }
        },
        'data': [{
            "type": "sentinel-2-l2a",
        }]
    },
    "evalscript": """
    //VERSION=3

    function setup() {
      return {
        input: ["B02", "B03", "B04"],
        output: {
          bands: 3
        }
      };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(
      sample,
      scenes,
      inputMetadata,
      customData,
      outputMetadata
    ) {
      return [sample.B04, sample.B03, sample.B02];
    }
    """
}
```

Coords for polygon

```
sample_coords = [
    [
        -94.04798984527588,
        41.7930725281021
    ],
    [
        -94.04803276062012,
        41.805773608962869
    ],
    [
        -94.06738758087158,
        41.805901566741308
    ],
    [
        -94.06734466552735,
        41.7967199475024
    ],
    [
        -94.06223773956299,
        41.79144072064381
    ],
    [
        -94.0504789352417,
        41.791376727347969
    ],
    [
        -94.05039310455322,
        41.7930725281021
    ],
    [
        -94.04798984527588,
        41.7930725281021
    ]
]
```

Unfortunately, could not upload images.

Comment: Is this S2L2A API, right? https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/sentinel-2-l2a/examples/

Comment: @ComradeChe yeah right. Took sample bboxes and coordinates for polygons from there. I also have other coords - same stuff, just white box.